# FullCalendar - How to save all new added/edited events in a JSON file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to write back to the same JSON file from where I've retrieved the old events, with all new added/edited events of the FullCalendar. I'm working on a Java swing application.

Can anyone please help me with the JavaScript function which I'm using Save onClick? OR would you please tell me why is not working?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
 function savedata(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#save").click(function () {
                var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                alert(eventsFromCalendar);
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: 'json/PrescribedWorkouts.json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        traditional: true,
                        data: { eventsJson: JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar) },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            debugger;
                            alert(xhr);
                        }

                    });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id='calendar' align="right"></div>
    <div id="save" class="save" align="right"><a href="" onclick="savedata()">
        <img src="../images/SaveChangesButton-Normal.png" alt="Save Changes"
             onmouseover="this.src='../images/SaveChangesButton-Hover.png'"
             onmouseout="this.src='../images/SaveChangesButton-Normal.png'"
        /></a></div>
```

OR is there any better way of saving events in a JSON file?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript cannot change files on the server, otherwise anybody could randomly change other people's websites. You need to have a script on the server (PHP, node.js, Ruby, whatever) and send the JSON data to that, then have that script replace/update the json file on the server. Btw, stating `dataType: "json"` says you want the response to be json.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you very much for your comments. My project is on Java swing application. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You have posted HTML and JavaScript, how is it a Java application?

Comment: @ChrisG I've loaded HTML Fullcalendar in a Swing pane. I was able to load all events on the calendar from Database through JSON page. But now I need to write/save back to JSON after add/edit events. Having limitation on swing application, can't think possible solution. Also tried JSP to load Fullcalendar but didn't work. I am new to Fullcalendar functionalities. Hope to figure out something. I've another question with details -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622107/fullcalendar-how-to-save-edited-events-in-a-json-file Thanks a lot for your help and consideration.